# Enumerating multiple sources in one sentence in APA-style?

Tags: citations

How are academic papers supposed to cite multiple sources in the same sentence when enumerating?

Which of the following examples does it right? (in APA)

1. Prevalent models within this context are model A, model B, and model C (source A, p. 12; source B, p. 202-203; source C, p. 1).
2. Prevalent models within this context are model A (source A, p. 12), model B (source B, p. 202-203), and model C (source C, p. 1).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both might be technically correct, but the second is better for specific sources because sources are alphabetical within citations, meaning that #1's citation might become "(source B, p. 202-203; source A, p. 12; source C, p. 1)", depending on the author last names. #2 keeps the sources linked to the models.

Comment: Thanks! I could not find an official APA reference explaining it. Could you provide a source to verify that both are indeed correct? Would appreciate it!

Comment: @2stefan2000 - the APA style manual is from https://apastyle.apa.org/products/publication-manual-7th-edition

Comment: @2stefan2000 - $25 on Amazon, undoubtedly available at your university bookstore.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it is better to use the second option so that there is no confusion in the sources, and it is possible to quickly refer to it without reading the text as in the first option.